# How to create a date using strings in vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I want to run a `for-loop` from sometime to some specific time. Let's say from the first day of the year to the last day:

I am given the year and I need to add the month and the day to it:

I am trying to concatenate into a full date string and the compiler keeps throwing errors:

```
dim dt as Date 
dim rs as recordset 
set rs = currentdb.openRecordset("select max(date) as dan from Atbl")

for dt = #1/1/year(now)# to #2/2/Year(rs!dan)#
    msgbox dt
Next
```

any help is appreciated. or any hint is welcome

Comment: Can you edit your question with the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DateSerial](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/DateSerial-Function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) should make this easier.

Give it values for year, month, and day in that order, and it will give you back the corresponding date as a Date/Time value.

```vb
for dt = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1) to DateSerial(rs!dan, 2, 2)
    msgbox dt
Next
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I was uncertain what you had in mind when you said last day of year.  That made me think `DateSerial(rs!dan, 12, 31)`  But I decided to just  translate what you already had to `DateSerial`

Comment: No problem. I usually don't ask the exact thing i am looking for, I look for similar stuff so I can figure the rest out. If I ask the exact thing I will get lazy :D

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found a solution quite fast: This works fine

```
dim dt as Date 
dim rs as recordset 
set rs = currentdb.openRecordset("select max(date) as dan from Atbl")

'save the first day as string first
Dim firstDay As String
firstDay = "1/1/" & Year(Now)
'convert to date
Dim firstDate As Date
firstDate = CDate(firstDay)

'save as string
Dim lastDay as string 
lastDay = "2/2/" & Year(rs!dan)

'convert to date
Dim lastDate As Date
lastDate = CDate(lastDay)

'works fine in here
for dt = firstDate to lastDate
    msgbox dt
next
```

Comment: No, don't go the string route, use DateSerial.

Comment: ok. as you can see above, i accepted the answer with dateserial not mine. and the string route is a possibility even if it is the one that is more efficient @Gustav